# Edit cart Magento doesn't show

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have developed a Web page where you can browse to products, buy them, checkout... But when you press on the "Edit" for the product, it shows a blank main page. Everything else appears, but not the edit for the product. That part remains white... Any idea on why?

You can try it [here!](http://www.bassarchery.com/bass.html).

Thanks.

Comment: doesn't find the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your local.xml:

```
<checkout_cart_configure translate="label">
    <label>Configure Cart Item</label>
    <update handle="catalog_product_view"/>
    <reference name="product.info">
        <block type="checkout/cart_item_configure" name="checkout.cart.item.configure.block"></block>
    </reference>
</checkout_cart_configure>
```